# Window.print() to Link-OS Zebra Printer?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, zebra-printers, zpl

Is it possible to print from Chrome Mobile (android) to a Link-OS Zebra Printer like [this one](https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/products/printers/mobile/zq500.html) using `window.print()`?

For example, when `window.print()` is called, a dialog box is opened asking the user to select the printer, orientation, etc.  If a Zebra Printer is connected via WiFi or BlueTooth, would the Zebra Printer show up as one of the options?

Also, would the file to be printed need to be a `zpl` file or would a `pdf` also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `window.print()` on Chrome for Android (Functionality for it was added in [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/4c172eea8b6649f1c1c620d1daa20ce733cee9e1)). There are no requirements that I can find regarding the file format.

Regarding that specific printer, as long as it is recognized by Android, it should work correctly.

Comment: Excellent. I'll revisit soon to confirm

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah did you get that to work? because we have the same workcase like in your description.

Comment: @FlorianWidtmann Unfortunately the project got killed and I never tried this solution so I cannot confirm or deny if it works. Can you?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah nah, we moved to starprint